# FB.login access token facebook javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
     window.location = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?"+access_token;
   }
 });
```

Which redirects me to the following results:

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 2500
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I not getting the proper access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use `response.authResponse.accessToken`.

Also, you need to append the `access_token` variable to the Graph request:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN`